# How to keep hashtag in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-router

I'm developing in Angular and every time I'm manually typing an url, the hashtag did get removed.

#### Example :

`mywebsite.com/some/url#anchor-id`
When I type enter, then it does change it to `mywebsite.com/some/url`

I looked and I don't know why Angular is removing this hashtag.
Is it something in the configuration of my project that I have to change ?

Already had a look at `useHash: true` but this isn't helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long search...

Angular doesn't have any configuration for that.

#### The problem

On each route, I did add the language of the page to the location -> `mywebsite.com/some/url` will became `mywebsite.com/en/some/url`.

This was the code

```js
this.location.replaceState(`/${this.selectedLang}${this.location.path()}`)
```

#### The solution

`location.path()` method does accept a variable -> `includeHash?: boolean | undefined`
passing true -> `location.path(true)` will then return the expected url.

So, this is the solution...

```js
this.location.replaceState(`/${this.selectedLang}${this.location.path(true)}`)
```